# Error at c# linq comparison

Tags: c#, linq, casting, compare

I have this linq and on my form there are textboxes which shows the databindings in text boxes  of the selected item from the listbox(datasource from database).

```
var j = (from s in db.Movies where s.Movietitle == listbox1.SelectedValue select s).First();
```

I must compare the movie title to the selected item of the listbox,they must be equal but my code can't continue to run because of the error:Warning    1   Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the right hand side to type 'string'

I casted (string) before the listbox but still no change. What can be the problem?

Comment: alternatively, use `s.Movietitle == listbox1.Text`

Comment: SelectedValue is of type object. use it's ToString Method

Comment: SelectedValue.ToString() same error

Comment: what type is Movietitle?

Comment: movietitle is a foreign key ncvarchar50 string

Comment: i am getting the same error after string cast,but the s.Movietitle and underlined with green

Comment: so is it still of the SQL type or the C# type? In the end you have to compare 2 same type objects

Answer (score 2):

Cast `listbox1.SelectedValue` as `sting` and use `FirstOrDefault()`, since query may return no results.

Use `s.Movietitle.ToString()`, to avoid `"Possible unintended reference comparison"`. The issue is that `s.MovieTitle` is reference type. If, for example it is of type `object`, the comparison operator `"=="` selected is comparing two objects...by reference as you may guess.

Comment: i am getting the same error after string cast,but the s.Movietitle and underlined with green

Comment: what's the definition of your s.Movietitle?

Comment: what about `s.Movietitle.ToString()`